# Как настроить структуру объекта в TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Здравствуйте. Помогите решить ошибку в TypeScript коде.
Есть функция, которая осуществляет запрос к серверу:

```
http.get(url)
.then((API: IResponse) => {
    if (API.data.response) {
        console.log(API.data.response);
    } else if (API.data.error) {
        console.log(API.data.error);
    }
});
```

Сервер всегда возвражает два вида объектов.

В случае ошибки:

```
{
  data: {
    error: {
        error_code: number
        error_msg: string
    }
  }
}
```

А в случае успеха:

```
{
  data: {
    response: {}
  }
}
```

В объекте `response` могут хранится любые поля и значения (Зависит от запроса).
Я описал интерфейс так:

```
interface IResponse {
    data: IResponseSuccess | IResponseError;
}

interface IResponseSuccess {
    response: {};
}

interface IResponseError {
    error: {
        error_code: number | string;
        error_msg: string;
    }
}
```

К сожалению компилятор TypeScript выдает ошибки:

- `Property 'response' does not exist on type 'IResponseSuccess | IResponseError'.`
- `Property 'error' does not exist on type 'IResponseSuccess | IResponseError'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как в момент компиляции TypeScript не знает какого именно типа придет `data` он бросает указанное исключение.

Для решения можно напрямую указать тип переменной

```
if ((<IResponseSuccess>API.data).response) {
    console.log((<IResponseSuccess>API.data).response);
} else if ((<IResponseError>API.data).error) {
    console.log((<IResponseError>API.data).error);
}
```

Либо воспользоваться [примером из учебника](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) и подсказать компилятору

```
function A(API: IResponse){
    var data = API.data;
    if (isResponseSuccess(data)) {
        console.log(data.response);
    } else if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
    }
}

function isResponseSuccess(data: IResponseSuccess | IResponseError): data is IResponseSuccess{
    return (<IResponseSuccess>data).response !== undefined;
}
```

[**Ссылка на пример**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IResponse%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20IResponseSuccess%20%7C%20IResponseError%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IResponseSuccess%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20response%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IResponseError%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20error%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20error_code%3A%20number%20%7C%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20error_msg%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20A(API%3A%20IResponse)%7B%0A%09var%20data%20%3D%20API.data%0A%09if%20(isResponseSuccess(data))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(data.response)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(data.error)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(data.error)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20isResponseSuccess(data%3A%20IResponseSuccess%20%7C%20IResponseError)%3A%20data%20is%20IResponseSuccess%7B%0A%09return%20(%3CIResponseSuccess%3Edata).response%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%3B%0A%7D)